# Update program by writing to the currently executing file

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ program which sooner or later will need to be updated. I want this to require as little interaction with the user as possible since the program runs constantly in the background and never terminates. I know that under normal circumstances, you can't write to a file that's being executed, so this is my question: is it possible for an application to modify itself without just running another executable and letting that one take over? I can't have more than one file.

Comment: Why can't you have more than one file? That is absurd.

Comment: It's a requirement and there's no way around it because of the environment in which it will be deployed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most programs using auto-update features use another executable to take over execution in order to avoid that problem.

However I see a somewhat simple solution:

- `old program` downloads `new program` into a temporary location
- `old program` starts `new program` (possibly with a special parameter) and terminates itself
- `new program` copies itself over `old program` (it should be ok for a running program to read itself, as long as it doesn't open itself for writing)
- `new program` runs `new program (copy)` with a special argument, and then terminates itself
- `new program (copy)` deletes `new program` and resumes normal operations

Is it clear enough ? :)

Comment: Yeah that actually made sense. I'll chew on that for a while to see if its possible or not for the way things need to be done. Thoughtful answer, someone update thisfor me.

Comment: Depending on the OS, you may be able to rename the file of a running executable. That would allow you to rename the existing file, move the new one to the proper name, and then run it directly from the proper name. Thus saving you a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to send a command to the program to tell it to terminate, then update the executable file, then relaunch.  It should also save any state so that it can continue where it left off when you restart it, if that matters.

Comment: Send the command from where? The program that's trying to update itself? Or from a separate update program? I think the user wants to write self-modifying code.

Comment: If the program is terminated, how do I get to the "update the executable file" part?

Comment: Frustrated, if self-modifying code (which I have no experience with) means writing assembly then ill have to take a different route. And the changes do have to save to disk for when the computer shuts down and stuff.

Comment: I'm trying not to encourage self-modifying code.  I was meaning a separate update program, or just the new copy of the program itself, telling the old copy to quit (see the answer by SirDarius below/above).

Comment: @moogoo: you would have your update program launch the new copy of the executable after killing the old version and copying over the new version.

Comment: The place where I said it must be obscure, but I've already said I can only have one file and unpacking one two from one isn't an option, so I can't have a separate update program.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of having to change the file that is executing, unless you do something like what sirdarius said.

Comment: Yes it does.  You still terminate the old program and copy over the new program.  The question is who initiates the termination, copy and relaunch.  It's pretty much the same thing, which is why I referred you to SirDarius's answer and voted it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are some languages like scripting languages or .NET/Java that can allow you to modify your own code. However, C++ does not provide any runtime code generation or modification tools. If you don't want to change language, you're stuffed. It's possible that you could get some nonstandard tool like LLVM to do it, I guess.